# How to check array for multiple values?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables

I have a variable that I got out of the database table like this:

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query) //The query is just: SELECT * FROM stuff_table WHERE userid='$userid'
{ 
$stuff = $r['stuff'];
}
```

The stuff variable looks like this: "cars, books, computers, foods" and I made it an array:

```
//I used:
$array_of_stuff = explode(",", $stuff); //This gave me an array.
```

Now I wanted to check its values, like this:

```
if(in_array("cars", $array_of_stuff) && in_array("books", $array_of_stuff))
{ 

//This line is the problem, I want it to check to see if it has "cars" and "books" in the array but this code is not working for that like it should. Instead of checking and finding both, it just goes on to the next elseif. 

echo "Cars and Books";
} elseif(in_array("cars")) {
//
echo "Only cars";
} elseif(in_array("books")) {
echo "Only books";
} else {
echo "Other stuff...";
}
```

The output I get from this is: "Only cars" instead of "Cars and Books".

So how can I make my code check the array for 2 or more values before continuing its if/elseif statement? Is it possible with the in_array function?

Var Dump:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(4) "cars" [1]=> string(6) " books" [2]=> string(10) " computers" [3]=> string(6) " foods" }
```

Comment: Your code looks just fine. What's the issue?

Comment: could you please give an output of `var_dump($array_of_stuff)`?

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL I want it to check the array for 2 values but it doesn't. I don't know why but it doesn't understand that the array has 2 values that I am looking for in it.

Comment: Add the output of var_dump($array_of_stuff) to your question and the solution will likely present itself straightaway.

Comment: I updated my question with the var dump.

Comment: You need to trim the leading spaces!

Comment: @JeffMeatballYang THANK YOU SO MUCH! THAT TOTALLY FIXED THE PROBLEM! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $array_of_stuff is actually set to `explode(",","cars, books, computers, foods")` as you described then the array will have leading spaces before the values other than cars. The `in_array()` function doesn't match substrings of the target elements, so "books" will not match against " books" in the array.

If you need to parse a string like that, you'll need to make sure you have an exact definition of the format it's in so you can correctly parse it into an array. If ", " is the only delimiter and that sequence always represents a delimiter (it's not ever escaped or quoted, for example), then you could change the `explode(",",...)` to `explode(", ",...)`. If this is data you're storing, be aware that you shouldn't invent your own format. Instead, use something like `serialize()` (which only PHP understands) or `json_encode()` (which is highly portable) to convert native types into a string (and the corresponding decode functions to decode it).

Beyond that, storing an array in a field of a row of a SQL table is often, but not always, a sign that the schema is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To copy all of an array's values into variables, use the list( ) construct:

```
list($variable, ...) = $array;
```

The array's values are copied into the listed variables, in the array's internal order. By default that's the order in which they were inserted, but the sort functions described later let you change that. Here's an example:

```
$person = array('name' => 'Mizan', 'age' => 26, 'wife' => 'Mita');
list($name, $age, $wife) = $person;
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can check 2 or more needles with `in_array()`, pass them in the first argument as array:

```
$searchStuff = array('cars','books');
if(in_array($searchStuff, $array_of_stuff)){
    // both found
}
```

See [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#example-4520), example #3

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm still getting the same output, "Only cars" instead of it finding both the values.

Comment: Trim the leading spaces off " books", etc.

Comment: Passing an array as the first argument of in_array() searches for a match of that array (it would look for `array('cars','books')` inside `$array_of_stuff`). It does not search multiple needles. Best to put it in a `foreach($needles as $needle) { ... }`